What is the use of "style" prop in material top tab navigator in react navigation (react native)?
So, I am new to react native. While developing a mini project, I faced a styling problem in material top tab navigator. It has a style prop, but when I am adding style, there is not change in top navigator. But I can change the styling of top navigator using
screenOption={{ tabBarStyle: { CSS styling} }

So my doubt is basically what's the use/purpose of style prop in material top tab navigator?
style prop in material top tab navigator
I tried to search the issue on internet and GPT but failed to get a clear explanation. Also GPT is suggestion to use tapBarOption which I cannot find in docs.

The correct names of the props are screenOptions and tabBarStyle:
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
  }}>
...
</Tab.Navigator>


But I want to know what is use of style prop in material top tab navigator???

I got it was typoerror. But is the use of style prop, if we can add styles from options?
